# Is there such a thing as a catastrophic shear thinning liquid?

Tags: material-science, non-newtonian-fluids

Non-Newtonian liquids can change their viscosity as a function of shear stress. Shear thinning liquids are those liquids whose viscosity decreases with shear stress. The examples I have seen of such liquids include ketchup and whipped cream.

Is there such a thing as a liquid whose viscosity changes catastrophically? I.E. it acts as something close to a solid, but becomes liquid fairly suddenly at a certain shear stress?

[image: Catastrophic shear thinning liquid]

If so, do these substances have a name, and where can I find out more about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; this is sometimes called a [complex liquid/fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_fluid) with a yield stress or a [viscoplastic material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscoplasticity) or, in the case of specific models, a [Herschel–Buckley fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel%E2%80%93Bulkley_fluid) or a [Bingham plastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_plastic), for example:

[image]

Granular materials and ductile metals exhibit similar behavior of flow to some degree after a load threshold is exceeded.

This and the associated [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid) should give plenty of search terms to explore.